# How to prevent the page CSS transitions when the browser’s back button is clicked

Tags: reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

I have a simple page transition that gets called when clicking a link. The new page animates from the bottom of the screen upwards to the top. It works fine, but it's also working when you click the back button in the browser. I don't want the transition to fire if someone clicks the back button on the browser, I just want to go back to the page at whatever scrolled position I left it in, in exactly the same way you would expect to happen by clicking the browser back button.

If I take the CSS transitions off then the back button works fine, so I need to somehow differentiate between the back button being clicked and a link being clicked and then play the transition accordingly.

I don't know if I need to setState or something else? I did try that, but it seemed to set the state variable after the transition had happened.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState }  from 'react';
import {Route, NavLink, Switch, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import './App.css';
import Home from './Home';
import About from './About';
import { CSSTransition, TransitionGroup,} from 'react-transition-group';
            
            
 const usePageMeta = (title, description) =>{
       const defaultTitle = "app-name";
       const defaultDesc = "meta description";
            
       useEffect(() => {
             document.title = title || defaultTitle;
                     document.querySelector("meta[name='description']").setAttribute("content", description || defaultDesc);
                }, [defaultTitl
    
        e, title, defaultDesc, description]);
            };
            
  const App = () =>{
            
            
                return (
                    <div className="App">
                        <div className="nav fixed top-0 left-0 z-10 w-full">
                            <NavLink exact to="/" activeClassName="active">Home</NavLink>
                            <NavLink to="/about"  activeClassName="active">About</NavLink>
        
        
                    </div>
        
        
                        <Route render={({location}) => (
        
        
                            <TransitionGroup>
                                <CSSTransition
                                    key={location.key}
                                    timeout={1000}
                                    classNames="fade"
        
                                >
                                    <Switch location={location}>
                                        <Route exact path="/">
                                            <Home usePageMeta={usePageMeta}/>
                                        </Route>
                                        <Route path="/about">
                                            <About usePageMeta={usePageMeta}/>
                                        </Route>
                                    </Switch>
                                </CSSTransition>
                            </TransitionGroup>
        
        
                        )} />
        
        
                </div>
        
        
            );
        
        
        }
        
        export default App;
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: I guess the transition is going into the history of the page and hence triggering a animation back to the original position. Can you replace the history with `useNavigate` hook and set the **replace** option true ? You can do the same with the history object. If not, a little more insight on how the transition is happening would be of great help.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use useNavigate. I'm using react-router-dom ^5.2.0 and I'm using react ^17.0.2. I cannot use later versions because somewhere along the lines Switch is not supported and the page transitions no longer work and then I'm back to square one. I have updated my question with the full code to give a little more insight.

Answer (score 0):

After some testing, I can see that this is bound to happen as the path is being loaded into the history of the browser.

**tl;dr**
This is not a quirk of the library, its just the way the browsers work. The current session always pushes state on the history object.
To prevent this you can do two things

- Overwrite the history state whenever the user navigates to a new path.
- Prevent the default action of the back button and redirect to the entry site.

##### Solution 1:

1. import createBrowserHistory from 'history' package and make a mutable history **outside** the app component.
2. make a immutable string of the start state when entering the app with `history.createHref(history.location)`
3. define an onClick handler which replaces the histories's top state to current location.
4. register a click handler on both NavLinks with the above defined function.
5. add a listener to the history (history.listen) and call history.goBack() if the action is pop.
6. call unlisten on unmount.

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

let history = createBrowserHistory();

const ContainerComponent = () => {
  // removed uselocation and usehistory hooks
  
  const location = history.createHref(history.location);
  
  const replaceHistory = () => {
    history.replace(location);
  }

  const unlisten = history.listen((location, action) => {
    if (action == "POP")
      history.goBack();
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => unlisten();
  })

  return (
    <div>
      <Navlink to='/' onClick={replaceHistory} />
      <Navlink to='/about' onClick={replaceHistory} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

##### Solution 2:

1. import createBrowserHistory from the 'history' module and create a mutable history object **outside** the app component.
2. add a listener to the history (history.listen) which goes back '-1' number of pages when it recives the "POP" action.
3. useEffect to 'unlisten' this event.

Note: this is assuming the user has to be navigated to the site which came from.

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

// Creates a mutable history state.
let history = createBrowserHistory();

const ContainerComponent = () => {

  //removed the eventlistener on window
  
  const unlisten() = history.listen((location, action) => {
    //remove the logging once satisfied with the result.
    console.log(`${location}, ${action}`);
    if ( action == "POP" ) {
      history.goBack();
    }
  })
  
  // removed 'popstate' evenhandler
  
  // adding useEffect to call unlisten on unmount
  useEffect (() => {
    return () => unlisten();
  }, [])

  const count = () => {
    setPageChanges(pageChanges + 1);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <NavLink to='/' onClick={count} />
      <NavLink to='/about' onClick={count} />
    </div>
    {/*... rest of the switch code with the transition ...*/}
  );
}
```

---

Edit: Solution 2 is refactored to use the 'history' package utilities.
This is seen more appropriate as the browser states are not touched with react code.

Also in the [docs](https://github.com/remix-run/history/blob/main/docs/getting-started.md#listening), it was mentioned that the history object is **mutable** which does result in some problems with mounting.

Caveat: this solution goes through all the states in between where the user is and where they started from, so expect some flashes of the earlier components.

Solution 1 also uses the same package, with the caveat that it will go to the first page and then goBack() 1 page more. This will be less of a flash then solution 2.

Comment: unfortunately Solution 1 has no effect and Solution 2 just throws up errors around const useEffect...

Comment: Yup now it works with all the tricks that could be used. I do suspect there is a simpler solution, but that would pertain to diving into the history stack's construction. Some Excercise for the reader

Comment: History will not install, no matter what version I try. It's time to reconsider what I'm doing I think. 10 days trying to get some simple page transitions working with react. Something like this shouldn't be rocket science. It's just too flaky.

Comment: I know, its just the version difference, the flaky part is there. Just a thing that i may have forgotten to mention, the history package installa with react router :P. Go ahead and import it, of using typescript (recommend), install @types/react-router

Comment: yeah it really doesn't work I'm afraid.